# Oracle scoping with subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

Just looking for some clarification on subqueries.  Lets say I have

```
select *
FROM my_table
LEFT JOIN a1 on a1.e = my_table.e
WHERE b>1
```

If I were to put a subqueries in each section of that what would be availabe to call?

Such as:

```
select *
FROM my_table
LEFT JOIN a1 on my_table.e = a.e
LEFT JOIN (select ....)a2 on my_table.c = a2.c
WHERE b>1
```

In that subquery could I reference a1?

Let me know if I need to clarify my question further.

Comment: No, you cannot reference tables from the `FROM` clause for subqueries used in the `FROM` clause.  Correlated subqueries are allowed in most other clauses.  Note:  This obviously doesn't apply to lateral joins available in the most recent versions of Oracle.

Comment: But if I had included a1 in my top SELECT could I then reference it in a2?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's possible with a `LATERAL` join:

```
select *
FROM my_table
  LEFT JOIN a1 on my_table.e = a1.e
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
      select ..
      from a1 
      where a1.e = 5
  ) a2 on my_table.c = a2.c
```